# Calling webservice on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to Calling the webservice without using the function `service_GetItemInfoCompleted()` in the below code?
Can it get the result without the function `service_GetItemInfoCompleted()`.

Any idea?

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Service1Client service = new Service1Client();
      service.GetItemInfoAsync(txt1.Text);
      service.GetItemInfoCompleted += new EventHandler<GetItemInfoCompletedEventArgs>(service_GetItemInfoCompleted);    
}

void service_GetItemInfoCompleted(object sender, GetItemInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      txb1.Text = e.Result;
}
```

Example 2

```
public void running()
{    
      ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient();

      test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient);  

      test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceAsync();
}

public void serviceClient(object sender, ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs e)
{

      answer = int.parse(e.Result.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above approach is the correct approach: Send the request to the service and when it returns, display the returned data in your textbox.

If you performed the same operation in one blocking call ...

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Service1Client service = new Service1Client();
    txtb1.Text = service.GetItemInfoAsync(txt1.Text);
}
```

... then your main UI thread would block until the data is returned from the service. If the service took several seconds to return, then your app's UI would 'hang' intermittently for several seconds, giving your users a very poor experience. This is a **bad** thing to do and something to avoid at all cost!

So we want to asynchronously call your service and wait for it to return without blocking threads. But rather than write the async code by hand, we can use the new `async` & `await` keywords in C# 5.0 to achieve the same goal as above but with less code & complexity:

```
private async void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Service1Client service = new Service1Client();
    string result = await service.GetItemInfoAsync(txt1.Text);
    txtb1.Text = result;
}
```

Note the use of `async` and `await` in the code above. The async keyword tells the compiler that you want it to build a state-machine which is driven by await states. Each await keyword tells the compiler to add a new state to the state-machine. When the code is executed, the await code sets up the state-machine to pick-up at the next operation when the awaited-upon task (`service.GetItemInfoAsync()` in this case) completes.

HTH.

Comment: Thx @Richard Turner. May i ask if without the txt1.Text, await still can be running?

Comment: May i add another different type of example in below of the code.